# How can i extract components from fastICA

Tags: java, r

I have problems to get ICA component fastICA in R. when i try to extract 6 component from fastICA function it give only one component but there should be 6 components . upto 5 it was worked perfectly but after the 5 it gives different different number of components.can anyone tell me what is the reason for that

Function and Parameters:

```
ICA6 <- fastICA(X, 6, alg.typ = "parallel", fun = "logcosh", alpha = 1, 
method = "R", row.norm = FALSE, maxit = 200, tol = 0.0001, verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example or at least `str()` output of  your `ICA6` object?

Comment: I posted a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115772/fastica-in-r-extracting-the-components This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

here is the last few lines of my output for ICA6 and ICA5

hpc-admin@aiken:~/gayan$ tail ICA6

[1992,] -1.755614e-01

[1993,] -1.931838e-01

[1994,] -1.403488e-01

[1995,]  4.952370e-01

[1996,]  3.798545e-02

[1997,] -8.870945e-02

[1998,] -1.847535e-01

[1999,]  2.084906e-01

[2000,]  2.235841e-01

hpc-admin@aiken:~/gayan$ tail ICA5

[1992,] -4.449966e-02  2.348224e-02 -0.1296879740  4.220189e-02 -0.1751827781

[1993,] -7.690094e-02  1.725353e-02 -0.1153838819  1.694351e-01 -0.1308105118

[1994,] -4.777415e-02  2.299214e-02 -0.1259907838 -6.011591e-03 -0.1605316621

[1995,]  4.354237e-02  2.295694e-02 -0.2499377363 -2.227481e-01  0.4414782035

[1996,] -3.848286e-02  2.121986e-02 -0.1361600020 -8.448882e-02 -0.0005046113

[1997,] -3.030994e-03  2.285310e-02 -0.1407370888 -1.215308e-02 -0.1062227838

[1998,] -3.988264e-03  2.335983e-02 -0.1497881709  1.787074e-02 -0.1982725941

[1999,] -7.483824e-02  1.096696e-02 -0.0672348301 -1.665848e-01  0.1489732404

[2000,] -7.123032e-01  1.123832e-02  0.5153474842 -1.785166e-01  0.1632015019