# fastICA in R (Extracting the Components)

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I primarily run analysis in SAS. However, I need to use fastICA in R.

I've conducted an Independent Component Analysis in R and am now looking to extract the actual components.

The code I've used to do this is as follows:

```
ica<-fastICA(final_all_truncated_s, n.comp = 100)
```

`ica` is now a list with 5 elements "X" "K" "W" "A" "S"

I would like to extract values from these elements, save to an excel file, and import into SAS. My question is, how to I extract the values from these elements so that I can export to an excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than saving the results to an excel format, I would recommend simply saving each component of the result to a separate CSV file.

This way you don't need any additional packages, and you have a software-independent file format that can easily be read by SAS, Excel, etc.

You can achieve this using a simple for-loop in R, e.g.:

```
for (x in names(ica)) {
    write.csv(ica[[x]], file=sprintf('%s.csv', x), row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
}
```

Here, `names(ica)` returns a vector of the list indices ("X", "K", "W", "A", and "S").

We then iterate over those indices, extract the corresponding list entries, and write a CSV file with the same name + ".csv", containing that entry from the list.

You might also consider spending a little time working in R to see if you can achieve what you want to do in that environment since it is capable of much of the same kinds of analyses as SAS.

Comment: I agree with you about the .csv. Thank you for clarifying this. I also agree with about R. As I use it more, I am blown away by the power. However, I'm getting ready to graduate and just don't have the time to learn a new language. But I am finding myself doing more work in R! 

So, I have ran this code and I have some clarifying questions:
1. Where is this .csv file stored? I see something generated but don't know how to access it.
2. I need to run this code for each element X, K, W, A, and S?

Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind. Your code works fine. I needed to create and save a workspace first. The .csv files pop up. Thank you very much.